# Spring Security: redirect to a different host when HTTPS is required

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-security, mod-jk

I have a question about Spring Security HTTPS redirect strategy.
First of all, the configuration:

1. Spring 3 Java Web App
2. tomcat after apache connected with jk
3. Spring Security 3

Using a configuration where the client connects directly to tomcat (i.e. no jk), I see that the https is managed using secure port redirect by configuring the security.xml file as follows:

```
<http>
   <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
   ...
</http>
```

now, here's the question: using tomcat after apache (with jk) the secured section is on a different host so that I have the following

- http (not secured host): www.myhost.com
- https (secured host): ssl.myhost.com

I'd like to know if is it possible to configure spring security to redirect to the secured host in case of https is required.
I see that there's a port-mapping configuration availbale, but I don't see something similar for the host.

```
<http>
  ...
  <port-mappings>
    <port-mapping http="9080" https="9443"/>
  </port-mappings>
</http>
```

Thanks in advance.

PS. the twofold hosts configuration is imposed by the hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the default behavior is a simple redirection to the same URI with https prefix, which is done in `RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint` invoked by the `SecureChannelProcessor`. You could easily implement the desired behavior by writing your custom `AbstractRetryEntryPoint` that not only changes the protocol, but also the host name.

Once you've implemented that class, configure the `ChannelProcessingFilter` with it, based on the sample given in its javadoc: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.3/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/channel/ChannelProcessingFilter.html

Comment: Did you manage to achieve the redirection to different host like this?

Comment: unfortunately, I'm forced to wait some technical delays which are not related to my activity. When the SSL server will be ready, I'll try your solution and I will tell you wether it works or not.